Is it possible to move a directory tree with standard MSI actions?
I want to move the directory tree "C:\ProgramData\a" with an MSI setup to the new location "C:\ProgramData\b". Is this possible standard MSI actions?
I am using the Windows Installer Xml (WiX) toolset (https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/main/) to build the setup.

MSI action MoveFiles (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/movefiles-action) can be used to move files but it does not move a complete directory tree (with sub folders).

The required functionality is provided by the Windows API function MoveFileExW (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefileexw). I could use it in a custom action, but I prefer to use standard MSI actions so that error handling (e.g. rollback after errors) is included.



It looks like WiX still doesn't provide a standard custom action to do recursive directory operations. It is possible to write an immediate custom action that dynamically adds temporary rows to the MoveFile table using MsiViewModify API with MSIMODIFY_INSERT_TEMPORARY flag, for each sub directory to move. This way you still get the benefits of the standard MSI action, like rollback.

Here is a general example of how to add temporary rows to an MSI table using a custom action: https://community.flexera.com/t5/InstallShield-Knowledge-Base/Dynamically-Add-and-Remove-Values-from-a-Combo-Box-at-Run-Time/ta-p/3981 -- As I found MoveFiles doesn't reliably remove empty directories, I have a deferred CA that calls RemoveDirectory recursively to remove empty dirs, but that was before RemoveFolderEx was added to WiX, which should simplify this task.
